# Visual Studio 2017 - Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I have Visual Studio 2017 installed (the latest release).  I added the Entity Framework package via Nuget, but I am unable to add an ADO.Net Entity Framework object to my project, as nothing appears in the item list.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

[List of data components available when adding a new item to the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2NjN.jpg)

Comment: Add more details, like what errors do you see, what are the steps you followed to install package, etc. Also add a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for that. After installing EF package did you refresh your Solution Explorer, Did you also create a .dbml schema containing your entities?

Comment: I have posted a picture of the list of items that I see when adding a new data item to the project.  Entity Framework is not appearing in this list or any other list.

Comment: Which version of EntityFramework did you install?

Answer (score 0):

I went with the latest Entity Framework, ver 6.2.  I ended up installing VS 2017 and re-installing.  That resolved the issue.  Turns out if you had an earlier release of VS 2017, you had to perform some manual steps on the extensions for SSRS and SSAS when SSDT was also installed.